# Splunk: How to grab certain section from result in splunk?

Tags: splunk, rex

I am using this query in splunk search -

```
index="some_index" | dedup source | sort -source | dedup sourcetype | table sourcetype, source
```

My result shows like this -

```
sourcetype                     source
-----------                 --------------

dev_architecture_dev1    /u01/splunk/etc/apps/dev-data/data/dev1/dev1-20150629133045.log
dev_architecture_dev2    /u01/splunk/etc/apps/dev-data/data/dev2/dev2-20150626124438.log
```

I want to grab only the year, month, day, hour, min and sec right before ".log". e.g. 20150629133045.
And then display it like 2015-06-29 13:30:45 in the 'source' column.

Is there a way to do it in Splunk6?

Thanks for looking at the question. Hoping to get some answers.

Comment: if you want to do it with splunk, the awk, sed, grep tags are irrelevant. Removing them.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the data

```
| rex field=source ".*?(?<dt>\d+)\.log"
```

Parse into time

```
| eval dt = strptime(dt, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

Format however you need

```
| eval dt = strftime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Output

```
| table sourcetype source dt
```